# Bold text in the email body show all the html word in the email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am using CSharp to create the send email function, now my problem is cannot work if I want bold the selected text. Below is my sample code:

```html
string emailSubject = $"Welcome to ABC company";

string emailBody = $"<b>Username:</b> {username}\n" +
                    $"<b>Password:</b> {userNewPassword}\n\n" +
```

The outcome result shows me in the email like below picture:

[image: img1]

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you. Do you know how to modify it?

Comment: Post the code that actually creates and sends an HTML email. Unless you tell whatever library you use that the body is HTML it will be treated as plain text